# DDR 3 RAM - Can I use two different brands of RAM on one motherboard?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have a zebronics motherboard and I want to ask: I have two different DDR3 RAMs with two different names. Below are the details

My questions are:

1. Can I use both RAMs with 1600 MHz?
2. And can I run them in my motherboard at the same time?
3. Or do I have to use both RAMs with the same MHz and also with same Company Brand name?

These are the RAM specs:

- Corsair DDR3 8GB Ram with 1600 MHz
- Hynix   DDR3 8GB Ram with 1600 MHZ

Answer (score 0):

To be honest as long as all of the number and hertz, line up you should be fine but it is best to get both the same brand for reliability and consistency purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Relating to your questions:

> Can I use both RAMs with 1600 MHz?

If they are specified with 1600Mhz frequency and your motherboard supports it, this should be fine.

> And can I run them in my motherboard at the same time?

Yes. Different manufacturers should not be a problem.
Different specs on the other hand would be.

> Or do I have to use both RAMs with the same MHz and also with same Company Brand name?

You have to use both RAMs with the same frequency/Mhz. So all RAMs have to support the same (used) frequency. But they do not have to be from the same manufacturer.